# ¿Como abrir un archivo en un punto especifico con c#?

Tags: c#, archivo

Me gustaría saber de que forma puedo abrir un archivo y que de inicio se muestre una linea exacta de apertura, actualmente ya puedo abrir archivo mediante la siguiente instrucción:

```
 Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe", rutaFile);
```

Esa instrucción abre mi archivo en visual studio pero yo quisiera que no solo lo abriera sino que aparte me indicara una linea en especifico al momento de abrirse.

Comment: pero no estas abriendo el archivo, estas ejecutando devenv y pasandole un archivo. vos queres abrir visual en un lugar en particular?

Comment: @gbianchi si exactamente, si es posible hacer eso la apertura de visual en un punto especifico o en caso contrario abrirlo en mi propia app en un punto especifico cualquiera me serviría. saludos

Comment: en tu app no se va a abrir, visual se abre solo. Y la verdad no se.. por cada proyecto, respeta donde lo cerraste. supongo que podras buscar donde guarda esa configuracion y modificarla a tu gusto.

Comment: Podrias usar **Visual Studio Code** y abrirlo con el siguiente comando `code --goto C:\TestFile.txt:12` donde 12 es el numero de linea del archivo en donde quieres que abra